# como abrir un juego hecho en LibGdx desde una actividad en android?

Tags: android, libgdx

He creado un pequeño juego en libGdx para android, ahora, quisiara saber como puedo abrir ese juego desde una actividad?, no he podido :(

Comment: Te recomiendo leer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y la guía para que aprendas [cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Así formularás preguntas de calidad y la comunidad podrá ayudarte a resolver los problemas que encuentres @OskarIvanScr

Comment: Primero como te ha dicho DevCodeG mejora tu pregunta para que podamos ayudarte, y segundo, ¿como has creado el juego, es decir, que IDE has utilizado?

Comment: He aqui la pregunta reformulada: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/184759/por-que-al-intentar-abrir-mi-pantalla-de-juego-en-libgdx-desde-android-a-partir

Answer (score 1):

Si ya tienes el codigo, y quieres usarlo en android, tienes que asegurarte que no tenga codigo de otras plataformas en espesifico y que solo sea el uso de libgdx y java regular...
[aqui sale como implementar para tadas las plataformas](http://www.edu4java.com/es/libgdx/arquitectura-ciclo-de-vida-libgdx.html)
tienes que saber que libgdx no es una libreria(.jar) corriente pues para usar libgdx tienes que generar los projectos con: [gdx-setup](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/download.html) el cual te creara los projectos para las plataformas que quieras, si intentas usar libgdx solo con el archivo **libgdx.jar** tendras error ya que vas a nesesitar los archivos nativos, pero si quieres aserlo sin el generador de projects, puedes hacerlo de forma manual con los recursos puros:[libgdx-nightly.zip](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/)  lo cual no es recomendable.

asi se mira una actividad que usa libGdx:

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplicationConfiguration;
import com.mygdx.game.MyGdxGame;

public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        initialize(new MyGdxGame(), config);
    }
}
```