# ¿por que al intentar abrir mi pantalla de juego en libgdx desde android a partir de una actividad obtengo una pantalla negra como salida?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Clase que se abre a partir de otra clase "AndroidLauncher extends AndroidAplication" desde la cual se lanza esta clase "pantalla" .

```
public class Mgame  implements ApplicationListener {

private SpriteBatch batch;
private Texture font;

@Override
public void create() {
    batch=new SpriteBatch();
    font=new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("badlogic.jpg"));


}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {

}

@Override
public void render() {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(10, 15, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(font,200,200);
    batch.end();

}

@Override
public void pause() {

}

@Override
public void resume() {

}

@Override
public void dispose() {

}
}
```

La pantalla (1) es la actividad inicial, al pulsar el boton esta nos dirige a la clase AndroidLaucher que se encarga de lanzar a la clase anterior generando como salida la pantalla (2). No se porque no me funciona, debería pintarse la textura, mas no sucede.

[image: Actividad inicial]
[image: Este es el resultado obtenido, pasados unos segundos todo finaliza y se cirra la aplicacion]

Obtengo como error lo siguiente:

> 07-29 14:43:35.522 11616-11616/com.example.diannaliset.game2
>   E/dalvikvm: Could not find class
>   'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
>   07-29 14:43:41.670 11616-11896/com.example.diannaliset.game2 A/libc:
>   Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x0000000d (code=1), thread 11896
>   (Thread-3232)

Answer (score 0):

El error que estaba cometiendo era que estaba generando un proyecto Android para el que luego le agregaba las librerías ***libgdx*** que pensaba eran suficiente para poder generar mis juegos, cosa que no es así. Lo que se tiene que hacer, y la mayoría de vosotros ya sabrá, se debe crear el proyecto mediante el **jar** de libjdx https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/download.html, este se encarga de generar todo el ambiente necesario para trabajar sin hacerlo nosotros mismos.

Answer (score 0):

aun que ya resolviste el error te recomiendo leer la doucumentacion de github.

aun error que note fue lo sigiente:

```
Gdx.gl.glClearColor(10, 15, 0, 1);
```

el problema es que ese metodo hay que pasarle el color de relleno en numero entre 0 y 1.
donde:

```
Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
```

es blanco, y:

```
Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
```

es negro..

lo puedes poner de una forma mas legible de la siguiente manera:

```
Gdx.gl.glClearColor(10 / 256f, 15 / 256f,/*ojo con las diviciones entre 0*/ 0, 1);
```

nota que el **256f** es de tipo flotante, ya que entero entre entero da entero.